# JavaScript Only: Monitor Any AJAX Request on the Page

Tags: javascript, ajax, response

I have some script files in my page that I can't access them because they load from other sources to my page. (It's a little bit complex to explain)

Those scripts have AJAX requests, so I want to do some work in their responses.

Is there any way in JavaScript (Not jQuery) that I can monitor any AJAX requests on the page so I can do something after those AJAX complete their requests? 
(Those AJAX requests are not in my hand anyway)

Comment: Short of rewriting the native XMLHttpRequest function, nope there's no way to do that.

Comment: @adeneo yes it's possible

Comment: override the function and put it in last js file

Comment: @Vikram, When the AJAX starts, it doesn't matter if you delete the function or something...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some native JavaScript I use to "hijack" any XHR (AJAX) requests, you should be able to take this and run with it (depends on how good you are, lol). I commented the part you will be interested in :)

```
var xmlreqc = XMLHttpRequest;
XMLHttpRequest = function ()
{
    try
    {
        this.xhr = new xmlreqc();
        return this;
    }
    catch (e) 
    {
        alert(e.message);
        return null;
    }
};

XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function (method, url, async, user, password)
{
    try
    {
        return this.xhr.open(method, url, async, user, password); //send it on
    }
    catch (e) 
    {
        alert(e.message);
        return null;
    }
};

XMLHttpRequest.prototype.setRequestHeader = function (header, value)
{
    try
    {
        this.xhr.setRequestHeader(header, value);
    }
    catch (e) 
    {
        alert(e.message);
    }
};

XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function (postBody)
{
    var myXHR = null;
    try
    {
        myXHR = this;
        this.xhr.onreadystatechange = function () { myXHR.onreadystatechangefunction(); };
        this.xhr.send(postBody);
    }
    catch (e) 
    {
        alert(e.message); 
    }
};

XMLHttpRequest.prototype.onreadystatechangefunction = function ()
{
    try
    {
        if (this.xhr.readyState == 4)
        {
            //here you will do whatever you want with the response, then send it onwards as if nothing happened
        }
        this.readyState = this.xhr.readyState;
        this.responseText = this.xhr.responseText;
        this.responseXML = this.xhr.responseXML;
        this.status = this.xhr.status;
        this.statusText = this.xhr.statusText;
    }
    catch (e) 
    {
        alert(e.message);
    }
    this.onreadystatechange();
};
```

Comment: Where in your code did you place it? Could you perhaps include the scripts you include in your html in your original post?

Comment: I've put it in the <head> tag.

Comment: Yes, but before or after any other scripts you include? Could you update your question with a sample of what is in your HTML when you define the scripts please? Because this script does work, I'm using it as an easy way to hijack any ajax requests on our old platform so that I can manipulate data to fit in with the new platform while we rewrite.

Comment: I think those requests are JSONP and not XHR standard. Anyway, I mark the answer correct cause this is not mensioned in my post. Thank you.

Comment: Ah okay. You didn't have to, but hopefully the code helps someone else :)