# Monitoring AJAX requests between a Flash applet and a server via a Google Chrome extension

Tags: ajax, flash, google-chrome-extension

I am playing a Flash-only game that uses AJAX to communicate with the server. The problem is that all the data is "drawn" and most of it not copy/pastable, so I end up retyping URLs and similar stuff from parts of it (i.e., from the chat).

I thought I'd make a simple page action extension for Chrome that would intercept all the AJAX communication between the game and the server, the way Developer tools can do it, and display only the data I'm interested in (parsing URLs and similar stuff is a no-brainer).

However, looking around the internet, I've found no info on how to do this. Many sites (including answers to some questions here) mention using Developer Tools (I'd prefer having a page action extension, simple enough to share with other players, but any other automation is welcome as well), some mention [`chrome.webRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) (which seems to be able to provide only the headers),...

I also thought of making a content script along the lines of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23904921), but since I'm trying to read the data between a Flash applet (not a web page) and a server, I don't think injecting a JavaScript code is possible.

So, my question is: can this be done and, if yes, how?

In case anyone got the wrong idea, the aim of this is only to monitor the communication and extract the parts I'd want to be able to copy/paste, not change any data (i.e., the purpose is simplification of the game play, not cheating).

Comment: Yes, `webRequest` is the right direction.

Comment: @Xan How do I get AJAX response bodies from it?

Comment: Hm. I'm afraid [you don't](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=104058). Then, you should look at [`chrome.debugger` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger), especially if it's for your own use. Note, this requires digging into the Debugging Protocol docs.

Comment: @Xan So, the answer to my question is that it cannot be done (in a way usable to the wider audience) at the moment. Thank you. Maybe add that (with links) as an answer, so I can accept it (in hopes that someone edits it in a month or two saying that it became possible)?